# Why doesn't my ANSI C function preserve the parameter value it sets?

Tags: c, string, pointers, concatenation, ansi-c

I'm using ANSI C with gcc on Linux for a project, and am trying to write myself some utility functions to make things a hair easier. In particular, I'm trying to write a "safe" string concatenation function that uses a fixed memory size and ensures that I never go over that size. This was my first crack at writing this function:

```
#define STRING_SIZE 1024
#define MIN(a, b) (a < b ? a : b)

void concatenate1(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    if (dest == NULL) {
        dest = malloc(STRING_SIZE);
        strncpy(dest, src, MIN(strlen(src), STRING_SIZE));
    } else {
        strncat(dest, src, STRING_SIZE - strlen(dest));
    }
}
```

The idea is that I can declare my string (char-pointer), and then start adding to it repeatedly, not needing to differentiate between initializing the string with a first value or concatenating to an existing value, because the function would handle it for me. In other words, here's some code that showcases this in action:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *myString;
    concatenate1(myString, "The ");
    concatenate1(myString, "quick ");
    concatenate1(myString, "brown ");
    concatenate1(myString, "fox");
    printf("%s\n", myString);
    return 0;
}
```

The trouble is that this results in a Segmentation Fault. So I wrote this version instead:

```
void concatenate2(char **dest, const char *src)
{
    if (**dest == 0) {
        *dest = malloc(STRING_SIZE);
        strncpy(*dest, src, MIN(strlen(src), STRING_SIZE));
    } else {
        strncat(*dest, src, STRING_SIZE - strlen(*dest));
    }
}
```

And I invoke it with this code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *myString;
    concatenate2(&myString, "The ");
    concatenate2(&myString, "quick ");
    concatenate2(&myString, "brown ");
    concatenate2(&myString, "fox");
    printf("%s\n", myString);
    return 0;
}
```

That version works fine. But I confess I find it a little bit annoying that I now have to prefix my variable with `&` in order to make the function work. What was going wrong with my first version? Is there any way to pass in a char pointer to a function and modify it directly, or is this the only legitimate way to update an existing string in C?

Comment: Do you understand that `MIN(strlen(src), STRING_SIZE))` will invoke the `strlen` twice? And that this macro won't work properly with arithmetic expressions?

Comment: I honestly didn't read past the first code fragment, but if you want it to be safe, as you say, you should at least check to verify that `malloc` succeeded in allocating memory.

Comment: `char **dest` is a pointer-to-pointer, so `&myString` is required.

Comment: `char *myString;` ==> `char *myString = NULL;` in your second implementation of `main`. You're throwing an *indeterminate* pointer value to the wolves.

Comment: C uses pass by value. The parameters are copies of the arguments

Comment: `strncpy(*dest, src, MIN(strlen(src), STRING_SIZE));` does not null character terminate `dest`.

Comment: Wow! These are all immensely helpful comments. I'm going to try to take them all into account (i.e. checking the return value of malloc, handling MIN in a better way, and being sure to null-terminate the string). Thanks guys!

Comment: With C, there is a rite of passage where each programmer tries to create "yet-another-string-type" and function set.  Its a good experience.   OP is just a step before that.  Good luck.

Comment: @chux: There is? Huh, so I'm not a good C programmer, as I never did ... ;-)

Comment: @Olaf There is still time as I suspect you still [in scope](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/e0/66/6f/e0666ff4774716dee1c47189970c77a3.jpg).

Comment: `char *myString` not necessarily initialized to NULL.

Comment: @chux: Mostly. But maybe I did my duty when I wrote two GUI libraries in Z80 and 68000 assembly language  already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example doesn't work because setting `dest = malloc(STRING_SIZE);` in your function only sets that value locally. It doesn't propagate back to the caller.

What you've done in your second example is the only way to make this work. There's no way to do what you're asking for in C. However, C++ has an analogous feature: reference arguments.